# Bound on $H^1_0$ norm of test function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading through a book of Courant Lecture notes on elliptic PDEs, and I'm uncertain how an inequality is derived.

The function $u\in H^1(B_1)$ satisfies

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\int a_{ij}(x)D_iuD_j\phi+cu\phi\,dx\leq\int f(x)\phi\,dx
\end{align}

for all $\phi\in H^1_0(B_1)$.  Fix $\phi=v\zeta^2$, where $v=(u-k)^+=\max\{u-k,0\}$ for some to be determined $k\geq 0$, and $\zeta\in C^1_0(B_1)$.  It has been shown that by integrating over the set $\{u>k\}$ we have

\begin{align}
\int a_{ij}D_iuD_j\phi\geq c_1\int|Dv|^2\zeta^2-c_2\int|D\zeta|^2v^2.
\end{align}

It is claimed that the inequality

\begin{align}
\int|Dv|^2\zeta^2\leq C\left\{\int v^2|D\zeta|^2+\int|c|v^2\zeta^2+k^2\int |c|\zeta^2+\int|f|v\zeta^2\right\}
\end{align}

follows (where each integral is over the set $\{u>k\}$).  I can't seem to determine where the third term on the right hand side of claimed inequality comes from.  Should there be a $v$ in the third term?  If not, why not?

Comment: Indeed, it's strange. I suppose your idea was to write 
$$uv \leq (u-k)v+kv \leq v^2 + kv $$ and, like me, you're stuck with one less k and one more v ;)

Comment: Right. The second term comes out nicely by writing $u=v+k$, but that gives one more $v$ than needed in term three.

Comment: How is fixed k?

Comment: For now, $k$ is any positive constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the trick : it's all in the $C$ constant.

Indeed, $vk \leq v^2 + k^2$

Hence

$$\int |c|uv\zeta^2 = \int |c|(v+k)v\zeta^2 = \int |c|v^2\zeta^2 + \int |c|vk\zeta^2$$

And this is inferior to

$$\leq \int |c|v^2\zeta^2 + \int |c|v^2\zeta^2+ k^2\int |c|\zeta^2$$

So it's inferior to

$$\leq 2 \left( \int |c|v^2\zeta^2 + k^2\int |c|\zeta^2 \right)$$

It's not obvious at first

Comment: Thank you very much! It is definitely not obvious at first. This book is fairly good at not being obvious. Again, thanks!